# Как проверить нет ли существующего значения в mysql?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Имеется простая форма записи в базу данных:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['nameto']) && isset($_POST['protec'])){


$name = $_POST['name'];
$nameto = $_POST['nameto'];
$protec = $_POST['protec'];



$db_host = ""; 
$db_user = "";
$db_password = "";
$db_base = '';
$db_table = "";


$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);


if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (name,nameto,protec) VALUES ('$name','$nameto','$protec')");

if ($result == true){
    echo "Успешно!";
}else{
    echo "Ошибка!";
}
}
?>
```

и банальная форма отправки:

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php" id="test">
    <input type="name" name="name" required />
    <input type="text" name="nameto" required />
    <input type="url" name="protec" required />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Как мне проверить, присутствует ли в базе одинаковые значения переменной name? Если присутствует, то выдать ошибку о том, что данное имя уже используется.

И еще бы хотелось узнать, как в моем случае при помощи AJAX запроса отправлять данные, не перезагружая страницу?

Comment: select запросом и проверь

Comment: @Jean-Claude Я почитал про select, но так и не понял как сделать запрос в моем случае. Я в php еще совсем зеленый и даже если вижу куда копать, самому разобраться сложно будет. Поэтому хотелось бы больше пояснений.

Comment: перед инсертом сделать такой же запрос $mysqli->query но SELECT, если он вернет результат - значит запись в бд есть.